# In Express, where do I place my sitemap.xml and robots.txt files?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm just learning Express and am trying to determine where exactly to put my sitemap.xml file and my robots.txt file. Do they go in the /public folder? Or do they go in the complete root of my Express application?

Thanks very much,

Chris

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They need to be publically accessible.  `public` seems a good spot for that.  Those files work because other external services load them from your website.  If they aren't accessible, they don't do anything.

---

Though, unless you site is very very simple, most dynamic websites generate a `sitemap.xml` dynamically.  Which means you register a route for it, poll your database for pages/objects that would have pages, and then generate xml based on that info.